# Store focus after refreshing the page

Tags: angular, typescript

I have an app that refreshes the whole page after selecting a value in a dropdown. I would like to make it easier for the user to work with the keyboard. For that I have to save the focus. Here I have programmed a small example. How can I save the focus on the menu items so that it is set even after reloading the page?

**EDIT: THIS EXAMPLE IS WORKING NOW**

template:

```
<div class="container">
    <button mat-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="menu" id="menu1">Menu 1</button>
    <mat-menu #menu="matMenu" tabindex="1">
        <button mat-menu-item>Item 1</button>
        <button mat-menu-item>Item 2</button>
    </mat-menu>
    <button mat-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="menu" id="menu2">Menu 2</button>
    <mat-menu #menu="matMenu" tabindex="2">
        <button mat-menu-item>Item 1</button>
        <button mat-menu-item>Item 2</button>
    </mat-menu>
    <button mat-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="menu" id="menu3">Menu 3</button>
    <mat-menu #menu="matMenu" tabindex="3">
        <button mat-menu-item>Item 1</button>
        <button mat-menu-item>Item 2</button>
    </mat-menu>
</div>
```

ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Renderer2 } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private renderer: Renderer2){}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    var element!: any;
    document.addEventListener('focusin', function () {
      var activeBtn = document.activeElement;
      if (activeBtn) {
        localStorage.setItem(element, activeBtn?.id)
      }
    }, true);
    var x =localStorage.getItem(element);
    if(x){
    document.getElementById(x)?.focus();
    this.renderer.addClass(document.getElementById(x),'focus')
    }
  }
}
```

szenario:

- navigate to the second element with tab --> menu 2 was focused
- after refreshing the page the focus should stay in menu 2

[image]

I implement this example in Angular, but solutions in JS,TS or Html would also helpful. But prefered solution is in Angular13

Comment: Every time the user changes focus, store the currently focused control in localStorage. In the component's onInit, read localStorage and focus the correct element.

Comment: @WillAlexander could you give a example, so that I can better understand it

Comment: You add a method call to each button, that method calls `localStorage.setItem('focus', yourValue)` where `yourValue` is your way of tracking which button was pressed. In ngOnInit you use `localStorage.getItem('focus')` to get it back, and you set the focus in your template accordingly.

Comment: @Will Alexander thank you for the hints, I have implemented a simple example which could transferred in my app :)

Comment: Awesome, happy to help :)